# SSAS to BI Tools via web service or Direct?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, rest, ssas, business-intelligence

I am building a application that has data in MSSQL, which is then transformed in SSAS cubes. My end goal is to expose the SSAS cubes to any BI tool including any custom built web app. Should I expose my SSAS cubes directly or have a interface in between that expose the SSAS cubes via REST Services. Please advise. There is authentication that i need to take care about.